# colcon build error on Ros2 Foxy Unity-Robotics-Hub example

Tags: unity-game-engine, cmake, ros2

I am following [ROS–Unity Integration tutorial](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/Unity-Robotics-Hub/blob/main/tutorials/ros_unity_integration/setup.md#install-unity-robotics-demo) for ROS2. I coppied unity_robotics_demo and unity_robotics_demo_msgs to my src folder from [here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/Unity-Robotics-Hub/tree/main/tutorials/ros_unity_integration/ros2_packages). When building unity_robotics_demo_msgs gives me an error.  I did source install/setup.bash and colcon build. Error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findrosidl_default_generators.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
  this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided
  by "rosidl_default_generators", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "rosidl_default_generators" with any of the following names:

    rosidl_default_generatorsConfig.cmake
    rosidl_default_generators-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "rosidl_default_generators" to
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "rosidl_default_generators_DIR" to a directory
  containing one of the above files.  If "rosidl_default_generators" provides
  a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

I am not sure how to add the installation prefix. In foxy/share there is rosidl_default_generators:

[image]

Comment: "I did source install/setup.bash and colcon build." - Have you performed the **second** `source install/setup.bash` after the `colcon build`, as manual describes?

Comment: yes, I did. But aftrer I copy those two packages into src folder, colcon build doesn't work. Oh, btw I am using virtual box and I downloaded ros as debian package using ros-foxy-desktop. In docker filer I can see it used foxy-ros-base. I checked everything from docker and it seems is the same as my environment. I am lost...